# Each normed space is isometrically isomorphic to a dense subset of a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

In our lecture on functional analysis, we had the following statement:
"Each normed space $X$ is isometrically isomorphic to a dense subset of a Banach space."

We were also given a proof, which goes as follows:

"Define $Y$ as the closure of $i(X) \subseteq X''$ (where $i: X \rightarrow X''$ is the linear isometry between a normed space $X$ and its bidual space $X''$). Since $Y$ is closed and $X''$ is a Banach space, we get that $Y$ is a Banach space."

I do understand the statements in the proof as such, but I don't understand how my statement actually follows from this proof. I think there might be just one final line of argument missing.

Thank you for your explanations.

Comment: $X$ is isometrically isomorphic to its image under $i$, and $i(X)$ is dense in $Y$, which is a Banach space.

Comment: @mathworker21 Thank you for your answer! That perfectly answered my question.

Comment: @mathworker21 Excuse me. Is $i(X)$ actually a vector subspace of $X''$ since $i$ is a linear transformation between vector spaces? Thank you.

Comment: @Wombat Do you agree $i(X)$ is a vector space? Do you agree it's a subset of $X''$?

Comment: @mathworker21 Yes, I do. I used to prove that the range of every linear transformation is a vector subspace of the codomain.

Comment: @Wombat So what's your issue/question?

Comment: @mathworker21 No, I'm done. Thanks for help.